How to have the Ubuntu Server select a wifi network based on priority or availability?
I'm running an Ubuntu Server (22.04) on a Raspberry Pi. I have two networks, a home network and a hotspot generated by my phone. I want to configure the Raspberry Pi running the Ubuntu server to choose the network with the highest priority (i.e home network over hotspot) or in the absence of a network, choose the other one, not only on boot but when its running too. The reason I want to do this is because the home network is not available, the Pi is headless, and I want to access the Pi while roaming. Both networks are wireless.

I've written a bash script to help with this: https://github.com/waltinator/net-o-matic It watches the connection, and when the connection drops, does a user-specified thing to try to reconnect or do something else.

Thank you for the script Walt. What I'm confused about is shouldn't priority be a feature in netplan? Wasn't there some priority setting? Why do we have to use a bash script for the same.

AskUbuntu is a Q&A site, not a conversation site. If you have new information on your original question, [edit] the question and add it. If you have a new question, [ask] it. Do not try to start conversations in a Comment. Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].
